# implementing UIButton programmatically using RxSwift, TDD and MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, tdd, rx-swift

Im trying to implement a UIButton programmatically using RxSwift, I have searched a lot and did not find anything useful, as I am new to this topics, there are some questions in my mind

I have a View With Two Buttons, Register and Login, by tapping this button, the only action is pushing to a new ViewController, here is the code for LoginViewController (I know i should not implement any code unless for a failed test to pass, it's just for showing what exactly im trying to do):

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var loginButton: UIButton?
    var registerButton: UIButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginButton = UIButton()
        registerButton = UIButton()

        view.addSubview(loginButton!)

        loginButton?.rx.tap
          .subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] in
                let enterPhoneNumberVC = EnterPhoneNumberViewController(nibName: "EnterPhoneNumberViewController", bundle: nil) as EnterPhoneNumberViewController
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(enterPhoneNumberVC, animated: true)
            })
          .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Question 1: as I understood, there is no need to notify viewModel as there is no logic in button action, is that right? or I should handle it through view model anyway?

Question 2: as this is a TDD project, how should i test below mentioned functionalities:

Check if tap is handled in ViewController

Test if touching button really does what I want

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t see any ViewModel related code in your snippet, what do you mean by notifying that?!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** I'd say that if there is no logic, then there is no reason to test and no need to run the code through the view model. That said, in the example you posted, there *is* logic. Each of those `?` in your closure represents an if check and if checks are logic. What if the LoginViewController was presented instead of pushed on a navigation controller? A common response to that question is something like, "well I know it isn't presented. I know the navigation controller exists." It's that *I know* part that is the problem.

My preferred approach here is to route the button tap to something that can push onto a navigation controller *without* having to check to see if it exists. That way there is no question (pun intended) as to its existence.

**Answer 2:** Both of the functionalities you mention are side effects and require integration tests, not unit tests. You can test that sort of functionality using UI testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think my question should be more clear, I did write test for checking the optional values, my problem is with the Rx part, as in Swift we can check if any selector responds to our button action with a code like this:

let actions: [String] = Button.actionsForTarget(ViewController, forControlEvent: event)! as [String] {
            return(actions.contains(actionName))
        }

I want to see if Rx has same thing or not, and how to mock viewController to check if calling onNext on LoginButton will actually do what I want, (i.e increasing a variable)

Comment: "It's that I know part that is the problem." So true, well said.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**. I agree, all the logic in your `loginButton` tap handling relates to navigation, and fits well within in the view controller domain.

**Question 2**. You reveal the need to test two different behaviors:

- Does `LoginViewController` *handle* the tap on `loginButton`?
- Is `EnterPhoneNumberViewController` pushed to the navigation stack?

Similarly to [@Daniel T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506441/daniel-t) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887675/809944), I'd recommend **decoupling the code that handles the tap from the code that pushes the new view controller**.

You can do this in many ways, my favorite is to have a *navigation delegate* in the view controller and test that it's called. Alongside that you can test that the type conforming to the delegate does the push.

```
protocol LoginViewControllerNavigationDelegate: class {
  func showEnterPhoneNumber()
}
```

```
func testLoginTapCallsShowEnterPhoneNumber() {
  let navigationDelegateSpy = LoginViewControllerNavigationDelegateSpy()
  let viewController = ...
  viewController.navigationDelegate = navigationDelegateSpy
  viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false) // loads the view

  viewController.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

  XCTAssertTrue(navigationDelegateSpy.showEnterPhoneNumberCalled)
}
```

```
class LoginViewControllerNavigationDelegateSpy: LoginViewControllerNavigationDelegate {

  private(set) var showEnterPhoneNumberCalled = false

  func showEnterPhoneNumber() {
    showEnterPhoneNumberCalled = true
  }
}
```

In your view controller you'd replace the direct push of `EnterPhoneNumberViewController` with

```
loginButton?.rx.tap
  .subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] in
    self?.navigationDelegate?.showEnterPhoneNumber()
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Which component conforms to `LoginViewControllerNavigationDelegate` is up to you. Ideally it would be the component that presented `LoginViewController` in the first place.

For the sake of this example let's assume it's a dedicated object, let's call it `LoginNavigator`.

```
func testShowEnterPhoenNumber() {
  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
  let navigator = LoginNavigator(navigationController)

  navigator.showEnterPhoneNumber()

  XCTAssertTrue(navigationController.topViewController is EnterPhoneNumberViewController)
}
```

This approach does require a bit more work, but it has the advantage of being decoupled. If you'll ever need to change how `EnterPhoneNumberViewController` is presented, say from a push to a modal, you can do it in a centralized and dedicated place, without having to dig into `LoginViewController`.